# Transforming data in a special format

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

First, I'll show how data looks, and then to what I'm trying it to transform.

```
data.head()

+------------+------+------+-------+---------+
|   Date     | col1 | col2 | col3  | Target  |
+------------+------+------+-------+---------+
| 2020-01-01 | a    | c    | f     |       1 |
| 2020-01-01 | b    | c    | g     |       0 |
| 2020-01-01 | b    | d    | g     |       1 |
| 2020-01-02 | a    | c    | g     |       1 |
| 2020-01-02 | a    | d    | f     |       0 |
| 2020-01-02 | b    | e    | g     |       0 |
| 2020-01-02 | a    | d    | g     |       1 |
| 2020-01-03 | b    | d    | f     |       1 |
| 2020-01-03 | b    | c    | g     |       1 |
| 2020-01-03 | b    | c    | g     |       0 |
+------------+------+------+-------+---------+
```

I'm trying to transform data in such a manner, that I want to group data by dates, where

**Volume Percentage**: sum of each of the feature categories corresponding to each date.

**Target percentage**: sum of target values corresponding to each of the feature categories at a specific date.

***NOTE***: The example shown below is for a specific date, but I want to do the same thing at the each date level.

```
transformed_data.head():

+------------+------------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|   Date     | feature_category | feature_name | volumne_perct | target_perct |
+------------+------------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| 2020-01-01 | a                | col1         |             1 |            1 |
| 2020-01-01 | b                | col1         |             2 |            2 |
| 2020-01-01 | c                | col2         |             2 |            1 |
| 2020-01-01 | d                | col2         |             1 |            1 |
| 2020-01-01 | e                | col2         |             0 |            0 |
| 2020-01-01 | f                | col3         |             1 |            1 |
| 2020-01-01 | g                | col3         |             2 |            1 |
+------------+------------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

I've written code for this in python, but that's not very efficient, and is computationally very expensive, also very lengthy code.

Hence, this time, I want to do this with **SQL**( and I'm not proficient in it), can you please guide me on the **logic** for the same, It'll be extremely helpful for me, cause I'm stuck at this part from a really long time.

Thanks

Comment: What is you python code? Interested in potential optimization?

Comment: @mozway  It's very long, I think it'll be better to do this thing in SQL, what do you think about this?

Comment: I don't know, it depends on your code ;)